# Access Bookmark works with Access Backend but not SQL Backend

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-express, bookmarks

I've recently upgraded an Access backend database to SQL Server backend & Access front end.  Mostly things are working but I've struck an issue with a bookmark on a form.  The form displays 3 date columns and I have used VBA to go to the first date of one of the columns that is today or greater than today with the on open event.

Here's the code that is still working in the Access frontend & backend database

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
' Find the record that matches the control.
 
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strCriteria As String
 
  strCriteria = "[PayPeriodPaidDate] >=Date()"
  Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
  rst.FindFirst strCriteria
  Me.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

Set rst = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now I have converted this to SQL Server Express nothing happens when the form opens.  It just goes directly to the first record of the form.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try test search on a number or text field instead of date/time field. Issue might be with way dates are stored.

Comment: double, triple check that the column is seen in the linked table as datetime. If it is not, then either change the data type on sql server to datetime (from datetime2), or re-link using newer ODBC drivers. If you modify the sql date column to datetime (from datetime2) then make sure you re-link the Access table(s), and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have converted the date field to *DateTime2* which the ODBC driver will read as text. If so, change the data type to *DateTime*.

Try to see if you find anything:

```vb
strCriteria = "[PayPeriodPaidDate] >=Date()"
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
rst.FindFirst strCriteria
Debug.Print rst.NoMatch
```

Comment: Much agree this is a possibility. the migration wizard by default uses datetime2. I would recommend the user check the linked table in design mode  - ensure that the date/time column is seen as date time - if this simply issue is missed, then the user will be posting questions and attempting to fix bugs for days on end - when zero code changes should be required.

Comment: You were all correct as the date was set as DateTime2.  It didn't work initially when I changed and relinked.  I had to put a CDate format at the start of the 3 date fields and it finally worked as it should.  Thanks so much for all your input :)